# Can we prove that an extension to a structure is consistent if the original structure is?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic

As I understand it, there is no way to prove that $\mathbb{N}$, as modeled by P.A., is consistent - meaning it may be possible to demonstrate *eg.* $5 = 3$. Therefore it is presumably also impossible to prove that $\mathbb{Z}$ - the extension of $\mathbb{N}$ with additive inverses - is consistent.

But could we at least prove that $\mathbb{Z}$ is consistent *if* $\mathbb{N}$ is? Could we do the same for $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by saying that a model is consistent. The things that are consistent or not are theories, not models. If PA is inconsistent it doesn't have any models whatsoever.

Comment: @Jack M Is there any chance you're confusing consistence with completeness right at the beginning of your reasoning (which thens proceeds on that false assumption)?

Comment: Well, can we use PA to prove that it's impossible to prove $5 = 3$ or some other contradiction?

Comment: @Jack: of course PA proves that $5 \neq 3$. But there's no reason for us to believe PA if it's inconsistent. The inconsistency of PA doesn't mean that something weird like $5 = 3$ is true, it just means that something weird like $5 = 3$ is provable from PA. You can still believe that the natural numbers exist and satisfy $5 \neq 3$ even if you think PA is inconsistent; that just means you think at least one of the axioms of PA fails to hold for the natural numbers.

Comment: Well my point is, if we use PA as our axioms for $N$, and then add more axioms for the existence of additive inverses, can we show that these axioms are consistent if PA is?

Comment: @Jack: no, because they aren't (but that isn't the question you meant to ask). One of the Peano arithmetic axioms is that $0$ isn't the successor of any natural number and additive inverses is inconsistent with this axiom.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have this backwards: *structures* are neither consistent or inconsistent, *theories* are!  Furthermore, given any structure $\mathfrak{A}$ over a (first-order) language, the set $\mathrm{Th} ( \mathfrak{A} )$ of all sentences true in $\mathfrak{A}$ is consistent.

The point of Gödel's (Second) Incompleteness Theorem is that unless PA is inconsistent, there is no way of proving the consistency of PA without transcending PA itself.  To quote George Boolos:

> It can be proved that if it can be proved that it can't be proved that two plus two is five, then it can be proved that two plus two is five, and math is a lot of bunk.

Consequently, there is no way to prove that models of PA exist (meaning that there is no way of demonstating that a particular structure $\mathfrak{N}$ satisfies all of the axioms of PA) without transcending PA.

However, it is possible to jump to significantly stronger theories to prove the existence of models of PA.  As an example, ZF proves the existence of the *smallest inductive set* (a set $I$ such that $\emptyset \in I$ and $x \cup \{ x \} \in I$ for all $x \in I$), call it $N$, and furthermore via a natural translation from the language of PA into the language of set theory, ZF proves that $N$ satisfies all of the axioms of PA.

In such strong enough set theories, we may then unproblematically construct the integers, the rationals, etc.

This may be seen as simply "passing the buck": While a strong enough theory $T$ may prove the consistency of PA, this just means that the consistency of $T$ implies the consistency of PA.  In particular, $T$ itself will be subject to Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem (as long as it is sufficiently simply presented).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by proving the existence of $\mathbb{N}$. It is possible to construct something that deserves to be called $\mathbb{N}$ under weak hypotheses, e.g. that the category of sets admits a natural numbers object (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/natural+numbers+object). What is not clear is whether the axioms of PA hold for this thing.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I was perhaps a bit too glib; thanks.  I'll make some substantive edits presently;

Comment: To that last paragraph: This is why I love working in ZFC+"There exists a Reinhardt cardinal". :-) *Instant rimshot sound here*

Comment: @Asaf: I’ve heard that you can prove $ {\sf{P}} \neq {\sf{NP}} $ in this system, or you can prove its negation, if you prefer. :)

Comment: @Asaf: Only one?  Why not Reinhardt-many Reinhardt cardinals (with a measurable above, of course)?!

Comment: It's easy to satisfy me with just one. I can work things up from there! :-)

Comment: @Arthur: One Reinhardt cardinal is sufficient for Asaf to settle the remaining Millenium Prize Problems. Asaf, don’t forget to invite me to your beachfront penthouse after your super-early retirement. =D

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you intended to ask is a bit different than what you had asked. So, I'll rephrase your question first. It is the case that the existence of a model of $\mathbb N$ cannot be proved without making some assumption about a universe outside of $\mathbb N$. Put a bit differently, it is impossible to display a model for the natural numbers without making use of some more fundamental notion, which we must take on faith.

Your question is then whether one can exhibit a model for the integerst provided one has a model for the natural numbers, and similarly for the rationals and the reals, and beyond. The answer is yes, it can be done, in many different yet essentially the same way. Moreover, there are various paths one can take, and luckily all the intermediate stops give essentially the same notions.

So, for instance, suppose you have a model $\mathbb  N$ for the naturals satisfying Peano's axioms. You can first introduce the integers by considering the follow formal construction: Let $X=\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$, and define the equivalence relation $(x,y)\equiv(u,v)$ precisely when $x+v=u+y$. Then one can show that the quotient is a model for the integers. Or, you can first introduce the non-negative rationals by considering $Y=\{(x,y)\mid y\ne 0\}$ and the equivalence relation $(x,y)\equiv(u,v)$ precisely when $xv=yu$. Now the quotient will be a model for $\mathbb Q_+$. These are very standard constructions, and can (with a bit of care) be performed interchangeably to produce an essentially unique (that means, any two are isomorphic) model of the rationals. Now, one can complete the rationals in any of several ways to arrive at an essentially unique model of the reals. Then one can construct the complex numbers, and so on.

So, if a model of the naturals exists then it can (within some ambient set theory) be used to construct models of the integers, rationals, reals, and so on.

Comment: Sure, but depending on the ambient set theory you need to be careful, e.g. whether you construct the real numbers using Dedekind cuts or Cauchy sequences might matter (see http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/real+numbers+object).

Comment: Yes, I was implicitly assuming ZF for the ambient set theory. Otherwise, as @QiaochuYuan points, different constructions may lead to different models.

Comment: I don't think I understand what "existence" means here. Can't I just say "consider a structure that satisfies PA", without ever mentioning any broader set theory or deeper axioms, and therefore basically just postulate that it exists?

Comment: @JackM yes, you can certainly say that. You can postulate the axioms and just pretend a model exists and work with it axiomatically. However, in order to use it to construct other models you need to do some things like take cartesian products, take quotients by equivalence relations etc. These constructions depend on the machinery of an ambient set theory, and there things can get a bit more subtle.